# NGINX reverse proxy for port 8765 with SSL is not working

Tags: ssl, nginx, ubuntu-18.04, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an Nginx server with SSL. And when I use proxy_pass to http://127.0.0.1:8765 with ssl added its giving "This site can’t be reached". Without SSL it was working correctly. If I send a request as http://domain-name:8765 in a web browser it gave the output correctly. Below is my configuration :

```
server {
        server_name domain-name.in;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;

        location / {
              proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8765;
  }

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain-name.in/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain-name.in/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = domain-name.in) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name domain-name.in;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Comment: Could you check whether the syntax is correct on configuration using `sudo nginx -t`

Comment: If nginX is used to terminate the SSL connection (and provide the public certificate) then you can/should use a non-SSL connection to your backend on port 8765. If you want the SSL to be terminated by the backend then you should proxy the raw TCP stream in nginX instead of HTTPS (http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html)